# How to compare two templates in go, the example get a unexpected result

Tags: go, compare

I want to compare two templates in Go, the simplified example below get an unexpected result. How to compare them?

https://play.golang.org/p/Q3eAxVEzcFp

I have tried DeepEqual but it does not work.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

// basicFunctions are the set of initial
// functions provided to every template.
var basicFunctions = template.FuncMap{
    "json": func(v interface{}) string {
        a, _ := json.Marshal(v)
        return string(a)
    },
    "split": strings.Split,
    "join":  strings.Join,
    "title": strings.Title,
    "lower": strings.ToLower,
    "upper": strings.ToUpper,
}

func main() {
    t1, _ := template.New("").Funcs(basicFunctions).Parse("{{.ID}}")
    t2, _ := template.New("").Funcs(basicFunctions).Parse("{{.ID}}")
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(t1, t2)) // want to be true, actually false
}
```

I want to get a `true` answer.

Comment: After there are some unexported fields inside template it is not really possible to compare that "private" fields outside of the template package.

Comment: Because the added FuncMap is featured in your example, I'm assuming that's a part you're looking to include in the comparison. But, function values are not comparable (unless both functions are nil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the two templates using the same data, but write each to a different buffer. Compare the bytes in the buffers. Repeat with different data until they diverge or you are satisfied that they are the same.

```
t1, _ := template.New("").Funcs(basicFunctions).Parse("{{.ID}}")
t2, _ := template.New("").Funcs(basicFunctions).Parse("{{.ID}}")
var b1, b2 bytes.Buffer
d := struct{ ID string }{ID: "test"}
t1.Execute(&b1, d)
t2.Execute(&b2, d)
fmt.Println(bytes.Equal(b1.Bytes(), b2.Bytes())) // true
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jz2Lbmf-4RY

There should be some set of data inputs that would satisfy you that these templates are the same, given that they output the same bytes given the same inputs.